# How to animate an ellipse?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Below my character, there will be some kind of animated ellipse (rotating). Like a halo.

However, I have no clue about how to do so. This was my original idea (which did not work):

With this sprite:

[image]

I run this code every 0.001 seconds:

```
-(void)updateCircle {
// Restore circle to normal scale
circle.scaleY = 1.0;
// Rotate circle by 1
circle.rotation += 1;
// Scale circle's Y-axis
circle.scaleY = 0.25;
```

}

The code managed to scale the circle to get my ellipse:
[image]

However, **it doesn't rotate as expected**. It rotates... well, normally. If you look at the ellipse image I got there, you should know how I want it to rotate.

The reason I scaled the image to 1.0, rotated, and then back to 0.25 was because I thought I could modify the texture perfectly and then scale it to get the proper result. That didn't happen...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Cocos sprites don’t work that way. You’re not doing anything to the image itself—the scale and rotation values that the sprite displays with aren’t affected by their old values. Probably what you want to do in this case is to add your `circle` as a child of another CCNode, rotate the circle in the same way you’re doing now (minus the scaling), and set the *parent* node’s `scaleY` to the value you want.